# Why don't property initializers call a custom setter?

Tags: kotlin

From the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters), custom setters are allowed:

```
class Test {
  var stringRepresentation: String
    get() = field
    set(value) {
      setDataFromString(value) 
    }

  init {
    stringRepresentation = "test"
  }

  private fun setDataFromString(value: String) { }
}
```

But you cannot have a custom setter without a custom getter (and initialize from the `init` block):

```
class Test {
  // Compilation error: "Property must be initialized"
  var stringRepresentation: String
    set(value) {
      setDataFromString(value)
    }

  init {
    stringRepresentation = "test"
  }

  private fun setDataFromString(value: String) { }
}
```

Although you can have a custom getter without a custom setter, no problem here:

```
class Test {
  var stringRepresentation: String
    get() = field 

  init {
    stringRepresentation = "test"
  }

  private fun setDataFromString(value: String) { }
}
```

So why can't you use a custom setter with a property initialized from within the `init` block, and why does the `init` block invoke the custom setter while the property initializer assigns directly, bypassing the custom setter?

```
class Test {
  var stringRepresentation: String = "" // Does not call custom setter
    set(value) {
      setDataFromString(value)
    }

  init {
    stringRepresentation = "test" // Calls custom setter
  }

  private fun setDataFromString(value: String) { }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Property initializers doesn't call custom setter because their purpose is to provide the default value.

Unlike in Java, in Kotlin not only local variables must be initialized before their first access but class properties as well.

In Java this is valid.

```
public class Test {
    public String str;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Test().str);
    }
}
```

In Kotlin this is not.

```
class Parent {
    var str: String?
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Parent().str
}
```

For this reason custom setter needs its property to be initialized either by property initializer or by the constructor. Take a look at the following example.

```
class Test {
    var stringRepresentation: String = "a" // Default value. Does not call custom setter
        get() = field
        set(value) {
            println("Setting stringRepresentation property to %s. Current value is %s.".format(value, field))
            field = setDataFromString(value)
        }

    init {
        this.stringRepresentation = "b" // Calls custom setter
    }

    private fun setDataFromString(value: String): String {
        println("Setting stringRepresentation property to %s.".format(value))
        return value
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Test().stringRepresentation = "c" // Calls custom setter
}
```

Property stringRepresentation is initialized to **"a"** opon instantiation of its class without calling setter.
Then init block is called and sets value to **"b"** using setter.
Then to **"c"** using setter.

Comment: Just having some difficulty understanding why adding a custom setter with an `init` block property initialization would fail to compile (since the property *is* being initialized). Is there a way to avoid code duplication in the initializer and custom setter, without delegating to another method? I would like to do some work during initialization and avoid writing to the property twice. The same work needs to be done whenever `set` is called.

Comment: Well, init block does initializes the property. But since the property has a custom setter init block uses this custom setter to do so. And since custom setter requires the property to be initialized either with default value or by the constructor, then you need to provide one of those.

Comment: About duplication... private method is the easiest way. But it depends on your use case.

Comment: Kotlin seems to be a good language, but in some places it does not do without a spoon of shit ... (((

Comment: @breandan, you can avoid the duplication by initializing the value to some random value, just for the sake of satisfying this requirement. Then in a constructor initializer block, you can do the actual initialization of the property value by setting it, which which will call the custom setter. For example, you might initialize a String to "" in the property initializer, then have an `init {}` block just below the property that uses values passed into the constructor to set the property again, calling the setter code. Even though this works, it seems like a flaw in the design of the language.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 Yeah, thanks for the reply. That’s what I was trying to avoid, duplicate initialization. But it seems necessary in this case.

Comment: Why do people so often explain kotlin by referring to java.  Shouldn't kotlin have its own justification?  It doesn't look good for kotlin if you have to learn java as well to understand how kotlin works.