# How to create an external property without a backing field in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, java-native-interface

I'm creating a wrapper for a C++ library in Kotlin, using JNI. In order to have a property implemented in  the C++ library, I need to mark a property's getter and setter as `external` to create `getX` and `setX` methods marked as `native`, [as indicated in the Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#using-jni-with-kotlin).

While this works as expected, **this also generates a backing field for the property**, which is not useful in my case because the value is located only in the native side.

For instance, I have the following class, containing an external property:

```kotlin
class Something {
    var name: String
        external get
        external set
}
```

The generated bytecode decompiled in Java (with `@Metadata` annotations stripped) by the "Kotlin Bytecode" tool in IntellIJ is as follows:

```java
public final class Something {
   @NotNull
   private String name;

   @NotNull
   public final native String getName();

   public final native void setName(@NotNull String var1);
}
```

As you can see, an unwanted `name` field is present. Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: This is actually a really important question as I discovered today. If the property is used in the constructor, the external setter will not be called unless the property is pre-populated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214452/why-dont-property-initializers-call-a-custom-setter